# Changing my permalink structure - will new layout conflict with existing page?

Tags: posts, permalinks, pages

My site has a blog page at `/blog/`, with links to blog posts. A post will have a URL starting at the root of the site, which is a bit jarring. I'd like to have the posts URLs appear as if they are within the blog section of the site.

My site currently has a permalink structure like the following:

`/2010/09/11/sample-post/`

I'd like to modify it to include a `blog` prefix:

`/blog/2010/09/11/sample-post/`

As I understand, WordPress should be able to handle the appropriate redirects.

My issue is the fact that I have the blog **page** at `/blog/`

If I change my post permalink structure, is there going to be any conflict with a page having a similar URL?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just tested it (briefly) on local test install and having static page at `/page/` and pretty permalinks starting with `/page/` doesn't seem to cause any issues.